# What is the negation to almost everywhere?

Tags: measure-theory, logic

We have some statement $P$ which holds almost everywhere in some complete measure space 
$(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mu)$.

Formally
$$ \exists N \in \mathcal{F} : \mu(N) = 0 : \forall x \in \Omega \setminus N : P(x) \ \text{holds}$$
so intuitively the statement $P$ holds in $\Omega$ except possible for some points in a null set $N$.

Now I think that the negation is
$$\forall N \in \mathcal{F} : \mu(N) \not = 0 : \exists x \in \Omega \setminus N : P(x) \text{ does not hold}$$
I can't quite put my finger on it, but this contradiction does not feel right. I have note taken any courses in formal mathematical logic so I am not sure if I have even constructed the negation correctly.

The contradiction above does not feel like a "working mathematicians" negation. In the past I have blindly assumed that the negation implies that
$$\exists N \in \mathcal{F} : \mu \left( \left\{ x \in \Omega : P(x) \ \text{does not hold} \right\} \right) > 0$$
but I was unable to prove a strict equivalence between these statements.

Comment: The negation of your first statement is:
$\forall N \in \mathcal{F} \text{ such that } \mu(N)  = 0,\,  \exists x \in \Omega \setminus N : P(x) \text{ does not hold}$

Comment: The problem in your formal approach is that you're using the colon "$:$" with two different meanings.  It helps to have the separate symbol such as "$.\ni.$" or "$s.t.$" to mean "such that".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is in your first statement, what does the second ":" mean? It's an "and" statement, really:

$$\exists N \in \mathcal{F}, (\mu(N) = 0 \text{ and } \forall x \in \Omega \setminus N : P(x) \ \text{holds}).$$

So the negation becomes:

$$\forall N, (N \not\in \mathcal{F}) \text{ or } (\mu(N) > 0 \text{ or } \exists x \in \Omega \setminus N, P(x) \text{ does not hold}).$$

Or equivalently ($P \text{ or } Q$ is the same as $\neg Q \implies P$):

$$\forall N, (N \not \in \mathcal{F}) \text{ or } ((\forall x \in \Omega \setminus N : P(x) \ \text{holds}) \implies \mu(N) > 0).$$

In English, if you have a measurable set such that $P(x)$ is true for all $x \not\in N$, then $N$ must have positive measure. Said in yet another way, you have to "miss" a set of positive measure if you want your statement to be true.

And since of course you can always consider the set $N = \{ x \in \Omega \mid P(x) \text{ does not hold} \}$, it does mean that this $N$ has positive measure (or is not measurable, which is a bit annoying in theory but not really in practice).

Comment: I think your "," and ":" are the same thing

Comment: @Omnomnomnom The "," is the same as the first ":" in OP's statement, but not the same as the second ":".

Comment: @NI right, so I guess I'm saying that OP's first ":" and third ":" are the same

Comment: imo we should let $:$ mean "such that" and $,$ just be a common comma used in language for this to make sense. Hence in your first formal statement $,$ should be $:$ and $:$ should be $,$? or do you choose to use $,$ as "such that" and $:$ as $,$ in common writing?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a careful formulation which works as you would expect in an incomplete measure space. "$P$ holds a.e." is defined to mean that $B=\{ x \in \Omega : \neg P(x) \}$ is contained in a measurable set $N$ with measure zero. Being very formal, we can write

$$(\exists N \in \mathcal{F}) \left [ \mu(N)=0 \wedge \left [ (\forall x \in \Omega) \neg P(x) \Rightarrow x \in N \right ] \right ].$$

I stress that this formulation is clunky only because of the possibility of incompleteness. If you have completeness (which you usually do), then you can just define it as "$B \in \mathcal{F}$ and $\mu(B)=0$", which is easier to negate. But note that even in the presence of completeness, you need to include the "$B \in \mathcal{F}$" part to get the correct negation.

Comment: Regarding your last paragraph, I think it would be simpler to redefine "$P$ holds a.e." as "There exists $N$, contained in a measurable set of measure zero, such that $P(x)$ holds for all $x \not\in N$".

Comment: @NajibIdrissi That's equivalent to this presentation (just contrapositive on the implication).

Comment: Ah, you're right, yes. Both are equivalent to "$\{x \mid \neg P(x)\}$ is contained in a null set".

Answer (score 0):

Let $$\alpha(N) \equiv N \in F$$ $$\beta (N)\equiv \mu (N)=0$$ $$\gamma (x) \equiv x \in \Omega/N$$
Then we can rewrite yoyr proposition as follows: $$\exists N [\alpha(N) \land \beta(N) \land \forall x (\gamma (x) \implies P(x))]$$
The negation then would be: $$\forall N [(\alpha (N) \land \beta (N)) \implies \exists x (\gamma (x) \land \lnot P(x))]$$